# Unable to copy my array values from viewcontroller to tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray array1` in a`UIViewController`. The values in `array1` are generated dyanamically. Now when i Switch to my `UITableViewController` I need to retrieve those `array1` values here in this table. Any basic method how to copy an array to the `UITableViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the table view controller a NSMutableArray property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array1;
```

Prepare for the segue programmatically, and its easy enough to pass the object like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showTableView"]) {
         ViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         destViewController.array1 = array1;
     }
}
```

Clearly, some of the text in the example needs to be changed to match your segue identifier and or variables, but that should do what you need.

Comment: yeah William, it worked absolutely., thanks for that. I have one more question for you.Whenever we need to Copy values between viewcontrollers.,  can we use the same method ?

Comment: Should always work out fine. As long as the destination VC has the property, it can be set in the prepareForSegue method. Happy coding.